# jQuery tablesorter does not work on my dynamically loaded table?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the jquery.tablesorter.js on a dynamically loaded table. I can get it to work flawlessly on a table that is loaded at runtime but not on a table that is built by Ajax.

I have followed many previous tips I have found on here to no avail. Currently I am running a script to call table sorter on page load, with click of a button my table gets built and I call the an update to table sorter after the table is loaded into my page.

I have the following code.

```
<!-- SCRIPT TO CALL TABLESORTER BEFORE TABLE IS BUILT -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Observation").tablesorter();            
    }
    );
</script>


<!-- SCRIPT TO BUILD TABLE AND CALL TRIGGER UPDATE TO TABLESORTER -->
<script>
    function loadObservations(status) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var a = 'Status=' + status;
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                buildOpenTable(this);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:57766/PALWebService.asmx/ObservationResult", true);

        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhttp.send(a);
    }
    function buildOpenTable(xml) {            
        var i;
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var table = "<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>SITE</th><th>BUILDING</th><th>OBSERVATION</th><th>ACTION</th><th>DATE OBSERVED</th><th>UPDATED BY</th><th></th></tr></thead>";
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CurrentObservation");            

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            table += "<tbody><tr><td class=col1>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("GUID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("SITE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("BUILDING")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("OBSERVATION_DETAIL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ACTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE_OBSERVED")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("UPDATED_BY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                "<span class=btnSelect id=btnSelect>Select</span>" +
                "</td ></tr ></tbody> ";
        }
        document.getElementById("Observation").innerHTML = table;           
        $("#Observation").trigger("update");
        window.location.hash = "#tableSummary";            
    }

</script>


<!-- TABLE SUMMARY OF OBSERVATIONS -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="tableSummary">
    <h3 class="text-center">Observation Summary</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="Observation" class="tablesorter table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered"  style="background-color:white"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an "update" is triggered, tablesorter is only expecting the contents of the `tbody` to have changed. It will ignore any `thead` modifications, and if you completely replace the `thead`, the click bindings are not reapplied.

In your case it appears that the `thead` isn't changing, so I would recommend only modifying the `tbody`:

```
function buildOpenTable(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var tbody = "";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CurrentObservation");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tbody += "<tr><td class=col1>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("GUID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("SITE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("BUILDING")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("OBSERVATION_DETAIL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("ACTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE_OBSERVED")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("UPDATED_BY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            "<span class=btnSelect id=btnSelect>Select</span>" +
            "</td ></tr >";
    }
    $("#Observation tbody").html(tbody);
    $("#Observation").trigger("update");
    window.location.hash = "#tableSummary";
}
```

Comment: Mottie, 

Ok that makes sense, but from shouldn't table be changed to tbody on line 8 in your code.

Comment: I have made all the changes and it doesn't appear you can set the innerHTML of a tbody. When I alert the tbody all my data is there, but how do I set the empty tbody in my table now. Thoughts?

Comment: You're right, line 8 should have been `tbody`... The problem is that I should have changed `innerHTML` to `.html(tbody)`... to empty a `tbody`, you can use `$("#Observation tbody").empty()`, but that isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed.